# How to retrieve the URL value from the YouTube V3 api?

Tags: json, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to retrieve details about YouTube videos using the V3 search API (https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search). I'm getting all the details of the videos in my JSON response but not the URLs of the videos. Can someone please help me on how to retrieve the URLs? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no the video url in the JSON, you need to use the videoId.

For example  you have a result like this one :

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/KciEh2k6bPhgTexCFr55nrDyEuo\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1031,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"F9iA7pnxqNgrkOutjQAa9F2k8HY/1Y85a6l1YSEQprOw66ptMsh0Bzw\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "KG0vtEsiPgs"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-01-04T20:06:53.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC5nc_ZtjKW1htCVZVRxlQAQ",
    "title": "Real Slow - You Flow",
    "description": "That little vocal snippet has got me hooked :) Download... http://bit.ly/1xHDPlX Real Slow https://soundcloud.com/realslowbeats ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KG0vtEsiPgs/default.jpg"
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KG0vtEsiPgs/mqdefault.jpg"
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/KG0vtEsiPgs/hqdefault.jpg"
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "MrSuicideSheep",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
```

Then you can extract the videoId to create the url to link the YouTube video.

For exemple `items[0].id.videoId` give me **KG0vtEsiPgs**

Then you need to concatenate the `videoId` with this url `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=`:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v='videoId'

Then you have the video link.